# How do I give a Ruby script executed via Rails console write permissions on Digital Ocean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, digital-ocean

I am deploying my Rails app to Digital Ocean.

I need to run a custom ruby script via the Rails console (or even on a job queue) and in some cases I want it to create a file and store it within my `config` directory.

Specifically, this is what the setup looks like:

```
Money.default_bank = MoneyOXR::Bank.new(
  app_id: ENV["APP_ID"],
  cache_path: 'config/oxr.json',
  max_age: 86400
)
```

So, what needs to happen is whenever it runs it needs to create the `config/oxr.json`.

However, when I run it, this is what happens:

```
Errno::EACCES: Permission denied @ rb_sysopen - config/oxr.json
```

Right now, I am just running it as `MyScript.run` at the command line in Rails console.

How do I do this?

Comment: have you tried changing the app folder permissions? something as suggested [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/permission-denied-on-deploying-rails)

Comment: @UdAY that suggestion is dead on the money. It worked for me. Do you mind writing up a complete answer and I will accept it. Try to make it as comprehensive as you can, i.e. directions about how to discover the users on the system and the user that is running the script and then how to modify the folder permissions. I could always do it, but this is an easy way for you to get some points, especially since you pointed me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the necessary folder permissions to `create/write` a file. You can do that by:

> chmod -R g+w app_path/config

This gives write permission to app `config` folder.

If you want to give permissions to a certain user then:

> ```
> => w || who; #list all of the currently logged in users
> => chgrp -R user_name app_path/config
> => chmod -R g+w app_path/config
> ```

**Edited by OP**

What also works is: `sudo chmod 777 oxr.json`